# %USERPROFILE% space error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to start my programm with

```
start %USERPROFILE%\.myProgramm\myProgramm.exe
```

But now i get a popup-message, that the folder C:\Documets is not found. This is caused by the missing abostrophes like `start '%USERPROFILE%\.myProgramm\myProgramm.exe'`. How to do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single quotes are not valid quoting characters in `CMD`. Use double quotes:

```
start "" "%USERPROFILE%\.myProgramm\myProgramm.exe"
```

**Edit:** added the missing `title` parameter.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot about the title parameter. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
start "" "%USERPROFILE%\.myProgramm\myProgramm.exe"
```

start starts a new cmd and then it parses the parameter to run. So it works;)